# pandas find strings in common among Series

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a Series of keywords extracted from a bigger DataFrame and a DataFrame with, among others, a column of strings. I would like to mask the DataFrame finding which strings contains at least one keyword. The "Keywords" Series is as follows (sorry for the weird words):

```
Skilful
Wilful
Somewhere
Thing
Strange
```

The DataFrame looks as follows:

```
User_ID;Tweet
01;hi all
02;see you somewhere
03;So weird
04;hi all :-)
05;next big thing
06;how can i say no?
07;so strange
08;not at all
```

So far I used a str.contains() function from pandas like:

```
mask = df['Tweet'].str.contains(str(Keywords['Keyword'][4]), case=False)
```

which works well finding the "Strange" string in the DataFrame and returns:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
Name: Tweet, dtype: bool
```

What I would like to do is to mask the whole DataFrame with the all Keywords array, so I can have something like this:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
7    False
Name: Tweet, dtype: bool
```

Is it possible without looping through the array? In my real case I have to search through millions of strings, so I'm looking for a fast method.

Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to achieve this is to use **pd.Series.isin()** with **map** and **apply**, with your sample it will be like:

```
df    # DataFrame

   User_ID              Tweet
0        1             hi all
1        2  see you somewhere
2        3           So weird
3        4         hi all :-)
4        5     next big thing
5        6  how can i say no?
6        7         so strange
7        8         not at all
```

---

```
w    # Series

0      Skilful
1       Wilful
2    Somewhere
3        Thing
4      Strange
dtype: object
```

---

```
# list
masked = map(lambda x: any(w.apply(str.lower).isin(x)), \                 
             df['Tweet'].apply(str.lower).apply(str.split))

df['Tweet_masked'] = masked
```

**Results:**

```
df
Out[13]: 
   User_ID              Tweet Tweet_masked
0        1             hi all        False
1        2  see you somewhere         True
2        3           So weird        False
3        4         hi all :-)        False
4        5     next big thing         True
5        6  how can i say no?        False
6        7         so strange         True
7        8         not at all        False
```

As a side note, **isin** only works if the whole string matches the values, in case you are only interested in `str.contains`, here's the variant:

```
masked = map(lambda x: any(_ in x for _ in w.apply(str.lower)), \
             df['Tweet'].apply(str.lower))
```

Updated: as @Alex pointed out, it could be even more efficient to combine both map and regexp, in fact I don't quite like **map** + **lambda** neither, here we go:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'.*({}).*'.format('|'.join(w.values)), re.IGNORECASE)

masked = map(bool, map(r.match, df['Tweet']))
```

Comment: Great thanks so much guys! I really appreciate your help! I'm now testing the methods in speed searching through millions of strings.

Comment: @fblamanna, I think speed-wise, using regexp will be faster as my method requires 3 x **apply** to transform the string content, efficiency wise,  using **map** will yield each **lambda** whereas **findall** may eventually max out memory

Comment: This works, but be very wary of applies as they slow things down as your data grows in size... Regexs are so fast because they are basically just lexical parsing. If you really are that concerned about memory usage (which shouldn't be the case here as you are already holding a DF in memory that is bigger or equal in size to the resulting df) and want to use apply, then at least use regexs in your lambda function.

Comment: @Alex, good point, let me update and provide our combinations

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
df['Tweet'].str.match('.*({0}).*'.format('|'.join(phrases)))
```

Where `phrases` is an iterable of phrases whose existence you are conditioning on.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I get an AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'findall'. Actually df['Tweet'] is a Series of strings.

Comment: You need to access the vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) method so : `df['Tweet'].str.findall(r'|'.join(phrases), flags=re.IGNORECASE).astype(bool)` should work

Comment: Whoops, didn't copy correctly from my IDE. Good catch.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine now, thanks! Even with a substring search inside the strings!

Comment: @Alex, as a side note, although current method is very quick, it could benefit even more if you apply **compiled** regexp.

Comment: @Anzel While that's true for python regexs in general, I just ran some timeit tests using compiled and uncompiled versions and they resulted in similar time durations. What you can do is use match instead of findall to speed things up (and cut down on memory usage).

Comment: @Alex, interesting, perhaps if the Series gets bigger it will eventually shows the difference, and YES I agree using **match** will definitely improve. You may consider rewriting the logic to make it yield and test on each row rather than on all rows? It will satisfy OP requirements for really large DataFrame. I am not 100% agreed on my **map** + **lambda** combinations, only because I need to control memory usage not to max out.

Comment: @Anzel I just tried some speed tests, and for some reason the uncompiled regex is running faster than the compiled regex passed as an argument... Beats me as to why - must be something to do with pandas implementation.

Comment: Hi all, I'm asking some more information.  What about if I want to detect the word found in the string? I would like, for instance, to add a new column on the dataframe called "Keyword Found" or something like this...

Answer (score 0):

A simple `apply` can solve this. If you can weather a few seconds of processing, I think this is the simplest method available to you without venturing outside `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("dict.csv", delimiter=";")
ref = pd.read_csv("ref.csv")

kw = set([k.lower() for k in ref["Keywords"]])
print kw

boom = lambda x:True if any(w in kw for w in x.split()) else False

df["Tweet"] = df["Tweet"].apply(boom)
print df
```

I tested it against exactly 10,165,760 rows of made-up data and it completed in 18.9s. If that is not fast enough, then a better method is needed.

```
set(['somewhere', 'thing', 'strange', 'skilful', 'wilful'])
          User_ID  Tweet
0               1  False
1               2   True
2               3  False
3               4  False
4               5   True
5               6  False
6               7   True
7               8  False
8               1  False
9               2   True
10              3  False
11              4  False
12              5   True
13              6  False
14              7   True
15              8  False
16              1  False
17              2   True
18              3  False
19              4  False
20              5   True
21              6  False
22              7   True
23              8  False
24              1  False
25              2   True
26              3  False
27              4  False
28              5   True
29              6  False
...           ...    ...
10165730        3  False
10165731        4  False
10165732        5   True
10165733        6  False
10165734        7   True
10165735        8  False
10165736        1  False
10165737        2   True
10165738        3  False
10165739        4  False
10165740        5   True
10165741        6  False
10165742        7   True
10165743        8  False
10165744        1  False
10165745        2   True
10165746        3  False
10165747        4  False
10165748        5   True
10165749        6  False
10165750        7   True
10165751        8  False
10165752        1  False
10165753        2   True
10165754        3  False
10165755        4  False
10165756        5   True
10165757        6  False
10165758        7   True
10165759        8  False

[10165760 rows x 2 columns]
[Finished in 18.9s]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It works! But I've been using the str.contains() method because sometimes I have to search for substrings or pieces of words in the DataFrame. I'm now trying to put this method in the boom function...