# pandas and "re" - search for total and partial strings

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

This an extended question from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195586/pandas-find-strings-in-common-among-series-and-return-keywords). I would like to search in strings total and partial strings like the following keywords Series "w":

```
rigour*
*demeanour*
centre*
*arbour
fulfil
```

This obviously means that I wanted to search for words like rigour and rigour**s**, **en**demeanour and demeanour**s**, centre and centre**s**, **h**arbour and arbour, and fulfil. So the keywords list I have is a mix of complete and partial strings to find. I would like to apply the search on this DataFrame "df":

```
ID;name
01;rigour
02;rigours
03;endemeanour
04;endemeanours
05;centre
06;centres
07;encentre
08;fulfil
09;fulfill
10;harbour
11;arbour
12;harbours
```

What I tried so far is the following:

```
r = re.compile(r'.*({}).*'.format('|'.join(w.values)), re.IGNORECASE)
```

then I've build a mask to filter the DataFrame:

```
mask = [m.group(1) if m else None for m in map(r.search, df['Tweet'])]
```

in order to get a new column with the Keyword found:

```
df['keyword'] = mask
```

What I'm expecting is the following resulting DataFrame:

```
ID;name;keyword
01;rigour;rigour
02;rigours;rigour
03;endemeanour;demeanour
04;endemeanours;demeanour
05;centre;centre
06;centres;centre
07;encentre;None
08;fulfil;fulfil
09;fulfill;None
10;harbour;arbour
11;arbour;arbour
12;harbours;None
```

This works using a w list without *. Now I had several issues in formatting the keyword w List of words with the * conditions, in order to run the re.compile function correctly.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your input series `w` needs to be adjusted to be used as regex pattern like this:

```
rigour.*
.*demeanour.*
centre.*
\\b.*arbour\\b
\\bfulfil\\b
```

Note that `*` in regex goes after something it does not work on its own. It means that whatever it follows can be repeated 0 or more times.

Note also that `fulfil` is a part of `fulfill` and if you want to have strict match you need to tell regex this. For example by using 'word separator' - `\b` - it will catch only string as whole.

Here is how your regex might look like to give you results that you need:

```
s = '({})'.format('|'.join(w.values))
r = re.compile(s, re.IGNORECASE)
r

re.compile(r'(rigour.*|.*demeanour.*|centre*|\b.*arbour\b|\bfulfil\b)', re.IGNORECASE)
```

And your code to have the replacement could be done with pandas `.where` method like this:

```
df['keyword'] = df.name.where(df.name.str.match(r), None)
df

            ID          name       keyword
        0    1        rigour        rigour
        1    2       rigours       rigours
        2    3   endemeanour   endemeanour
        3    4  endemeanours  endemeanours
        4    5        centre        centre
        5    6       centres       centres
        6    7      encentre          None
        7    8        fulfil        fulfil
        8    9       fulfill          None
        9   10       harbour       harbour
        10  11        arbour        arbour
        11  12      harbours          None
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one question, what's the difference between rigour.* and center*? Should they have the same ".*" part at the end?

Comment: Well spotted. Yes, they should have same ending `.*`. I have corrected this typo.

Comment: Thanks a lot. To get the new 'keyword' column right even when searching through a longer string, I suggest making the `mask = [m.group(1) if m else None for m in map(r.search, df['name'])]` and then `df['Keyword'] = mask` should return the correct keyword found in each string.