# pandas get "single" keywords from DataFrame string search

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

this is a follow-up of [this previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195586/pandas-find-strings-in-common-among-series-and-return-keywords). I have a Series of strings w called "British" like this:

```
British
\bSkilful\b
\bWilful\b
\bfulfil\b
\b.*favour.*\b
\bappal\b
\bappall.*\b
\barbour.*\b
\barmor.*\b
\bstrange\b
\brumor.*\b
\b.*color.*\b
\b.*centre's\b
```

and a DataFrame df like this:

```
 User_ID     Tweet
 01          hi all
 02          see you something
 03          that's my favourite spot
 04          the strangest rumors
 05          my appal is nice
 06          check my rumor
 07          #brborboncheckruMoreThanever
 08          look @mycentre's
```

I would like to get a new column containing the SINGLE keywords found in the strings. So far I did:

```
 List = pd.read_csv('w.txt')
 r = re.compile(r'.*({}).*'.format('|'.join(List['British'].values)), re.IGNORECASE)
```

and then mask the DataFrame:

```
  masked = map(bool, map(r.search, df['Tweet']))
  df2 = df[masked]
```

Then I masked it again to add the 'keyword' column:

```
 mask = [m.group(1) if m else None for m in map(r.search, df2['Tweet'])]
 df2['keyword'] = mask
```

which returns:

```
   User_ID                     Tweet         keyword
2        3  that's my favourite spot  favourite spot
4        5          my appal is nice           appal
5        6            check my rumor           rumor
7        8          look @mycentre's      mycentre's
```

So the boolean mask works fine and detect only the tweets containing at least one keyword. But what if I would like to extract only the single keyword found? The final DataFrame should be as:

```
   User_ID                     Tweet         keyword
2        3  that's my favourite spot       favourite
4        5          my appal is nice           appal
5        6            check my rumor           rumor
7        8          look @mycentre's        centre's
```

Thanks so much for your kind help.

Comment: In the instance of index 2 in your returned dataframe, are you looking to have a different `keyword` column if there are multiple keywords? So, `keyword1` would have "favourite" and `keyword2` would have 'spot', for example?

Comment: It is impossible, you cannot differentiate between  `centre's` and `mycentre's`, both are chunks of non-whitespace chars. The logic that you describe is `[m.group(1).split()[0] if m else None for m in map(r.search, df2['Tweet'])]`