# Extract keywords from a title,relevant, and final column math

Tags: string, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, text-extraction

I have a DataFrame that is structured in the following way:

```
 Title;         Total Visits;    Rank
 The dog;       8           ;    4
 The cat;       9           ;    4
 The dog cat;   10          ;    3
```

The second DataFrame contains:

```
Keyword;     Rank
snail ;      5
dog   ;      1
cat   ;      2
```

What I am trying to accomplish is:

```
 Title;         Total Visits;    Rank  ; Keywords    ; Score
 The dog;       8           ;    4     ; dog         ; 1
 The cat;       9           ;    4     ; cat         ; 2
 The dog cat;   10          ;    3     ; dog,cat     ; 1.5
```

I have made use of the [following reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195586/pandas-find-strings-in-common-among-series-and-return-keywords), but for some

```
df['Tweet'].map(lambda x: tuple(re.findall(r'({})'.format('|'.join(w.values)), x)))
```

return null.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#create list of all words
wants = df2.Keyword.tolist()
#dict for maping
d = df2.set_index('Keyword')['Rank'].to_dict()
#split all values by whitespaces, create series
s = df1.Title.str.split(expand=True).stack()
#filter by list wants
s = s[s.isin(wants)]
print (s)
0  1    dog
1  1    cat
2  1    dog
   2    cat
dtype: object

#create new columns
df1['Keywords'] = s.groupby(level=0).apply(','.join)
df1['Score'] = s.map(d).groupby(level=0).mean()

print (df1)
         Title  Total Visits  Rank Keywords  Score
0      The dog             8     4      dog    1.0
1      The cat             9     4      cat    2.0
2  The dog cat            10     3  dog,cat    1.5
```

---

Another solution with lists manipulation:

```
wants = df2.Keyword.tolist()
d = df2.set_index('Keyword')['Rank'].to_dict()
#create list from each value
df1['Keywords'] = df1.Title.str.split()
#remove unnecessary words
df1['Keywords'] = df1.Keywords.apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item in wants])
#maping each word
df1['Score'] = df1.Keywords.apply(lambda x: [d[item] for item in x])

#create ne columns
df1['Keywords'] = df1.Keywords.apply(','.join)
#mean
df1['Score'] = df1.Score.apply(lambda l: sum(l) / float(len(l)))

print (df1)
         Title  Total Visits  Rank Keywords  Score
0      The dog             8     4      dog    1.0
1      The cat             9     4      cat    2.0
2  The dog cat            10     3  dog,cat    1.5
```

---

**Timings**:

```
In [96]: %timeit (a(df11, df22))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.71 ms per loop

In [97]: %timeit (b(df1, df2))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.55 ms per loop
```

Code for testing:

```
df11 = df1.copy()    
df22 = df2.copy() 

def a(df1, df2):
    wants = df2.Keyword.tolist()
    d = df2.set_index('Keyword')['Rank'].to_dict()
    s = df1.Title.str.split(expand=True).stack()
    s = s[s.isin(wants)]
    df1['Keywords'] = s.groupby(level=0).apply(','.join)
    df1['Score'] = s.map(d).groupby(level=0).mean()
    return (df1)

def b(df1,df2):   
    wants = df2.Keyword.tolist()
    d = df2.set_index('Keyword')['Rank'].to_dict()
    df1['Keywords'] = df1.Title.str.split()
    df1['Keywords'] = df1.Keywords.apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item in wants])
    df1['Score'] = df1.Keywords.apply(lambda x: [d[item] for item in x])
    df1['Keywords'] = df1.Keywords.apply(','.join)
    df1['Score'] = df1.Score.apply(lambda l: sum(l) / float(len(l)))
    return (df1)

print (a(df11, df22))    
print (b(df1, df2))
```

EDIT by comment:

You can apply `list comprhension` if there are `Keywords` with more as one words:

```
print (df1)
         Title  Total Visits  Rank
0      The dog             8     4
1      The cat             9     4
2  The dog cat            10     3

print (df2)
   Keyword  Rank
0    snail     5
1      dog     1
2      cat     2
3  The dog     8
4  the Dog     1
5  The Dog     3

wants = df2.Keyword.tolist()
print (wants)
['snail', 'dog', 'cat', 'The dog', 'the Dog', 'The Dog']

d = df2.set_index('Keyword')['Rank'].to_dict()
df1['Keywords'] = df1.Title.apply(lambda x: [item for item in wants if item in x])
df1['Score'] = df1.Keywords.apply(lambda x: [d[item] for item in x])
df1['Keywords'] = df1.Keywords.apply(','.join)
df1['Score'] = df1.Score.apply(lambda l: sum(l) / float(len(l)))
print (df1)
         Title  Total Visits  Rank         Keywords     Score
0      The dog             8     4      dog,The dog  4.500000
1      The cat             9     4              cat  2.000000
2  The dog cat            10     3  dog,cat,The dog  3.666667
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. With the first option Keywords and Score yield NaN with the exception of one result which displays one keyword (although it should have two) and the string manipulation option ends with a ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero.

Comment: Where I am having trouble is -if the string is contains for example:"Star Wars: Rouge One" and the keyword is  "Star Wars" the string is stored as "["Star", "Wars:", "Rogue", "One"] and there is no match.

Comment: If there is two or more words as keywords, solution is more complicated. The main problem is spliting in `Title` column in `df1`, if there is combination one word keywords and two and more words as keywords. Then spliting by whitespaces split only one word keywords. Is possible to solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, some of the keywords are compound words and I have not found a way to adjust for titles that have compound words. If there was a way to duplicate  `checkResult=[]
mList=["dog","cat","apple","The dog", "the Dog", "The Dog"]
mString = "The dog is runnng after the cat"
for item in mList:
    if item in mString:
        checkResult.append(item)`

 using pandas _I think that would solve the problem_.

Comment: Thank you. But now I am on visit during all weekend, so or post new question or wait to Monday, sorry.

Comment: No worries any help you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: I add solution, only there is problem with duplicates - it also  check `dog` and `The dog` in first row. But i think it is problem in sample, in real data it can works nice. Please check it.

Comment: It appears to be working great but is case sensitive. I am going to try and figure out how to read the Title column in lowercase.

Comment: you can use [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) -  `df1.Title.str.lower.apply(lambda x: [item for item in wants if item in x])`

Comment: Thanks this is the result: df1['Keywords'] = df1.Title.str.lower.apply(lambda x: [item for item in wants if item in x])
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: Maybe i forget bracket. `df1['Keywords'] = df1.Title.str.lower().‌​apply(lambda x: [item for item in wants if item in x])`

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks for all of your help.