# Singular and plural phrase matching in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a pandas Series and another sentences Dataframe as follows(only a summary of the data is added here).

```
#df
0  1 teaspoon vanilla extract
1  2 eggs
2  1 cup chopped walnuts
3  1 cup rolled oats
```

and

```
#ingredients

0   vanilla
1   walnut
2   oat
3   egg
```

I am applying following function to check whether the ingredients in the #ingredients are available in the #df fields.

```
masked = map(lambda x: any(ingredients.apply(str.lower).isin(x)),            
             df[0].apply(str.lower).apply(str.split))
df['Ingredient Available'] = masked
```

The problem is when the plural form of the ingredient exists in the eg: `eggs` masked field returns `false`(even thought `egg` in the #ingredient list). Can anyone suggest me a method to make this work without considering the whether its singular or plural? (I followed the path suggested in the [pandas find strings in common among Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156666/pandas-find-strings-in-common-among-series) and please dont mark this as a duplicate as that question didnt mention about such problem).

Thank You very much

Comment: So are the 2 dfs the same lengths? it looks like ingredients is just one large lookup table, correct?

Comment: Yes, its large as 381 ingredients.

Comment: I think I want to look for a method to look for thing like this. `egg in eggs` as it return true. the think unclear in for me is who to add this to the function

Comment: You might take a look at incorporating the [TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/dev/quickstart.html#words-inflection-and-lemmatization) library.  It supports inflection changes (`singularize()` and `pluralize()`).  This would catch plurals that aren't like their singular equivalents (e.g. goose and geese).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your column names are for the first df, in my example they are both ingredients but the following would work:

```
In [256]:
df1['ingredients'].apply(lambda x: any(df['ingredients'].str.lower().str.contains(x.lower())))

Out[256]:
index
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
Name: ingredients, dtype: bool
```

Essentially this performs a reverse lookup, we iterate over the ingredients series using `apply` and then test for membership of this  ingredient in the whole df using `contains` this will handle plurals in this case.

Comment: first df doesnt have a column name so I simply used df[0] and used just ingredients as the next (Its a series). But the results are not as you mentioned. Everything came out false

`masked=df[0].apply(lambda x: any(ingredients.str.lower().str.contains(x.lower())))`

Comment: No you need to do this the other way around: `ingredients.apply(lambda x: any(df[0].str.lower().str.contains(x.lower()))) – `

Comment: No luck. everything seems to be returning False

Comment: Well you're going to have to post actual raw data and code to reproduce your error, on your sample you've posted my code works

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. There are 381 variables in the #ingredients I mentioned only few. I provided the sample codes when I integrated your code here. `ingredients=pd.Series(["vanilla extract","walnut","oat","egg"])` `df=pd.DataFrame(["1 teaspoon vanilla extract","2 eggs","1 cup chopped walnuts","1 cup rolled oats","nnnnfgsdfg","asffadsf"])` and then I applied your function. `ingredients.apply(lambda x: any(df[0].str.lower().str.contains(x.lower())))` The results were providing true for first 4 ingredients and didnt return false for the final two "nnnnfgsdfg","asffadsf"

Comment: Here is the link to code and data if you want to have more idea about the code. I tried everything for hours with no luck. https://trinket.io/python/684c463c68