# Multiple Phrases Matching Python Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

This is with reference to my previous question [Singular and plural phrase matching in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273012/singular-and-plural-phrase-matching-in-pandas). Since the expected functionality was not achieved from the help given by others, I am posting it with the approach I have followed and what I actually needed to achieve.

Here below are the two phrases datasets and code.

```
ingredients=pd.Series(["vanilla extract","walnut","oat","egg","almond"])

df=pd.DataFrame(["1 teaspoons vanilla extract","2 eggs","3 cups chopped walnuts","4 cups rolled oats","1 (10.75 ounce) can Campbell's Condensed Cream of Chicken with Herbs Soup","6 ounces smoke-flavored almonds, finely chopped","sdfgsfgsf","fsfgsgsfgfg"])
```

What I simply needed was match the phrases in the ingredients Series with the phrases in the DataFrame. As a Pseudo code,

> If ingredients(singular or plural) found in phrase in the DataFrame,
>   return the ingredient. Or otherwise, return false.

I have developed a code from instructions given in other question I asked.

```
results=ingredients.apply(lambda x: any(df[0].str.lower().str.contains(x.lower())))
df["existence"]=results
df
```

[image]

The problem with my code is that it only checks the number of items in the series and stop looking for it. The result I really needed is as follows,

```
    0                                            existence
0   1 teaspoons vanilla extract                  vanilla
1   2 eggs                                       egg
2   3 cups chopped walnuts                       walnut
3   4 cups rolled oats                           oat
4   1 (10.75 ounce) can.....                     False
5   6 ounces smoke-flavored almonds.....         almond
6   sdfgsfgsf                                    False
7   fsfgsgsfgfg                                  False
```

Can anyone tell me how should I achieve this functionality? I have spent days testing it but no luck finally. Thank You everyone.

Comment: *The result I really needed is as follows* then what do you get now?

Comment: @Thomas The Picture right below the code is what I am currently getting. What I need is mentioned at the end.

Comment: @stribizhev you mean to apply the function as follows ? This produced me an error. `results=ingredients.apply(lambda x: where(df[0].str.lower().str.contains(x.lower()), True))`

Comment: The problem is that `any` returns a boolean, and you should look for the method to return just the element that meets certain criterion. I thought there was one similar to other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`numpy` string operations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html):

```
In [131]:

df.columns = ['val']
V = df.val.str.lower().values.astype(str)
K = ingredients.values.astype(str)
df['existence'] = map(''.join, np.where(np.char.count(V, K[...,np.newaxis]),,
                                        K[...,np.newaxis], '').T)
print df
                                                 val        existence
0                        1 teaspoons vanilla extract  vanilla extract
1                                             2 eggs              egg
2                             3 cups chopped walnuts           walnut
3                                 4 cups rolled oats              oat
4  1 (10.75 ounce) can Campbell's Condensed Cream...                 
5    6 ounces smoke-flavored almonds, finely chopped           almond
6                                          sdfgsfgsf                 
7                                        fsfgsgsfgfg
```

There are 2 steps:

```
In [138]:
#check if each ingredients in found
np.char.count(V, K[...,np.newaxis])
Out[138]:
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
In [139]:
#if it is found, grab its name
np.where(np.char.count(V, K[...,np.newaxis]),
                      K[...,np.newaxis], '').T
Out[139]:
array([['vanilla extract', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', 'egg', ''],
       ['', 'walnut', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', 'oat', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', 'almond'],
       ['', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', '']], 
      dtype='|S15')
```

Comment: Thank You very much. This works and this is by far the best code I got. Could you please tell me how to add Nan or any other default value to existence column so that I can easily filter them out. I tried df.fillna(0) but it didn't work

Comment: Could do: `df.ix[df.existence=='', 'existence'] = np.nan (or other fill-in value)`. However, it is worth considering whether you want to have `nan` or `''` for missing string values. One way or the other may cause headaches down the road.

Comment: I need to have something for missing values so that I can easily filter them out. There is some small thing I am facing with this code as some plural phrases are not filtered out. Like I have `strawberry`  in my ingredients list but I want it printed when it find out `strawberries` in the phrases. I will ask that in another question. Thanks again!