# Singular and Plural words matching with Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

This question is an extension to my previous question [Multiple Phrases Matching Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311008/multiple-phrases-matching-python-pandas). Although I had figured out the way after an answer to solve my problem, some typical problem in singular and plural words appeared.

```
ingredients=pd.Series(["vanilla extract","walnut","oat","egg","almond","strawberry"])

df=pd.DataFrame(["1 teaspoons vanilla extract","2 eggs","3 cups chopped walnuts","4 cups rolled oats","1 (10.75 ounce) can Campbell's Condensed Cream of Chicken with Herbs Soup","6 ounces smoke-flavored almonds, finely chopped","sdfgsfgsf","fsfgsgsfgfg","2 small strawberries"])
```

What I simply needed was match the phrases in the ingredients Series with the phrases in the DataFrame. As a Pseudo code,

> If ingredients(singular or plural) found in phrase in the DataFrame,
>   return the ingredient. Or otherwise, return false.

This was achieved by an answer given as follows,

```
df.columns = ['val']
V = df.val.str.lower().values.astype(str)
K = ingredients.values.astype(str)
df['existence'] = map(''.join, np.where(np.char.count(V, K[...,np.newaxis]),K[...,np.newaxis], '').T)
```

And I also applied following to fill the empty cells with NAN so that I can easily filter out the data.

```
df.ix[df.existence=='', 'existence'] = np.nan
```

The results we as follows,

```
print df
                                                 val        existence
0                        1 teaspoons vanilla extract  vanilla extract
1                                             2 eggs              egg
2                             3 cups chopped walnuts           walnut
3                                 4 cups rolled oats              oat
4  1 (10.75 ounce) can Campbell's Condensed Cream...             NaN    
5    6 ounces smoke-flavored almonds, finely chopped           almond
6                                          sdfgsfgsf              NaN  
7                                        fsfgsgsfgfg              NaN
8  2 small strawberries                                           NaN
```

This was correct all along but when singular and plural words mapping are not like `almond`=> `almonds` `apple`=> `apples`. when something appear like `strawberry`=>`strawberries`, This code recognize it as a `NaN`.

To improve my code to detect such occurrences. I like to change my ingredients `Series` to `data Frame` as follows.

```
#ingredients

#inputwords       #outputword

vanilla extract    vanilla extract 
walnut             walnut
walnuts            walnut
oat                oat
oats               oat
egg                egg
eggs               egg
almond             almond
almonds            almond
strawberry         strawberry
strawberries       strawberry
cherry             cherry
cherries           cherry
```

So my logic here is whenever a word in `#inputwords` appear in the phrase I want to return the word in the other cell. I other words, when `strawberry` or `strawberries` appear in the phrase, the code just out put the word next to it `strawberry`. So that my final result will be

```
                                                 val        existence
0                        1 teaspoons vanilla extract  vanilla extract
1                                             2 eggs              egg
2                             3 cups chopped walnuts           walnut
3                                 4 cups rolled oats              oat
4  1 (10.75 ounce) can Campbell's Condensed Cream...             NaN    
5    6 ounces smoke-flavored almonds, finely chopped           almond
6                                          sdfgsfgsf              NaN  
7                                        fsfgsgsfgfg              NaN
8  2 small strawberries                                           strawberry
```

I cannot find a way to incorporate this functionality to the existing code or write a new code to do so. can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# your data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ["1 teaspoons vanilla extract","2 eggs","3 cups chopped walnuts","4 cups rolled oats","1 (10.75 ounce) can Campbell's Condensed Cream of Chicken with Herbs Soup","6 ounces smoke-flavored almonds, finely chopped","sdfgsfgsf","fsfgsgsfgfg","2 small strawberries"])

# Here you create mapping
mapping = pd.Series(index = ['vanilla extract' , 'walnut','walnuts','oat','oats','egg','eggs','almond','almonds','strawberry','strawberries','cherry','cherries'] , 
          data = ['vanilla extract' , 'walnut','walnut','oat','oat','egg','egg','almond','almond','strawberry','strawberry','cherry','cherry'])
# create a function that checks if the value you're looking for exist in specific phrase or not
def get_match(df):
    match = np.nan
    for key , value in mapping.iterkv():
        if key in df[0]:
            match = value
    return match
# apply this function on each row
df.apply(get_match, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

consider using a stemmer :)
http://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html

taken straight out of their page:

```
    from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
    stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
    stemmer2 = SnowballStemmer("english", ignore_stopwords=True)
    >>> print(stemmer.stem("having"))
    have
    >>> print(stemmer2.stem("having"))
    having
```

Refactor your code to stem all words in the sentence before matching them with the ingredients list.

nltk is an awesome tool for exactly what you're asking!

Cheers